# How to edit grafana.ini in kube-prometheus-stack

Tags: grafana, kube-prometheus-stack

I want to add Google OAuth2 authentication for Grafana that was deployed inside kube-prometheus-stack, and I was trying to follow [this documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-security/configure-authentication/google/), but I cannot find the way how to edit `grafana.ini` if deployed in that helm package.

How can I access it?

Answer (score 3):

You can define `grafana.ini` in the `values.yml` of Helm chart of `kube-prometheus-stack` because it uses [default values from Helm chart of Grafana](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/grafana/values.yaml) it has `grafana.ini` defined in it.

```
grafana:
  nodeSelector:
    beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
  namespaceOverride: "monitoring"
  grafana.ini:
    users:
      viewers_can_edit: true
    auth:
      disable_login_form: true
      disable_signout_menu: true
    auth.anonymous:
      enabled: true
      org_role: Editor
  sidecar:
    dashboards:
      enabled: true
      label: grafana_dashboard
      path: https://grafana.com/api/dashboards/10475/revisions/1/download       
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://$host/oauth2/auth"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$request_uri"
    pathType: ImplementationSpecific
    hosts:
    - grafana.azure.development.k8s.abc.net
    tls:
    - hosts:
      - grafana.azure.development.k8s.abc.net
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).